# How to click on table row in using VBscript IE automation

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation, html-table, row

I am very new for vbscript IE automation, I want to click on `<td>` for select the row. please html code, please provide vbscript code how to handle this through script.

```
<tr class="mcl_data_unsel">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
        &nbsp;<b>HPOrderNo</b> =  <font color="#aa0000"><b>82P980080009</b></font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```html
<tr class="mcl_data_unsel"><td style="white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;<b>HPOrderNo</b> =  <font color="#aa0000"><b>L6P981027002</b></font></td></tr>
```

Now I want to click on this row, then only it will select.

Comment: This is the code <tr class="mcl_data_unsel"><td style="white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;<b>HPOrderNo</b> =  <font color="#aa0000"><b>82P980080009</b></font></td></tr>

Comment: Please show what have you done so far, otherwise it is much less likely that you will get a desired answer. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: It's better to edit your question and include the missing parts there so that other people will be able to give answers, too, thus I would suggest you to do that instead, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is not working? Show us your effort. SO does not provide "Code writing" service.

Comment: whenever click on HPorder , some style needs to on selected row